# GotoBLAS for Intel Architecture - Seeking Download Links, and Compilation Guide for Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, compilation, blas

Right now I'm compiling Eigen to use for linear algebra calculations within my application. However, I'd much prefer to use GotoBLAS Intel version for optimal performance.

Is there a simple way to (a) acquire the necessary source code and (b) compile it within Visual Studio 2008? I've found GotoBLAS2 online but it seems to be engineered for microarchitectures and I'm unsure how to easily compile it in VS for use within a C++ environment.

Advice would be greatly appreciated, many thanks for your time.